# i wanna update my formset factory images post, i am able to update posts text fields but formset factory images are noot updating

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, formsets

I have searched this issue but couldn't get the right answer where as there are so many questions being asked before related to that.

i am using a model for post with multiple fields and other model (having foreign key of post model) for multiple image fields.I Want to update the posts i create.

Here's my views.py for update_post

```
def update_post(request, post_id):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostPicture, form=AddPictures, extra=10, min_num=1)
            post_form = get_object_or_404(Posts, pk=post_id)
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = AddFile(request.POST, instance=post_form)
                formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=PostPicture.objects.filter(post=post_id))
                if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    formset.save()
                    for form in formset:
                        if form:
                            image = form['image']
                            photo = PostPicture(post=form, image=image)
                            photo.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Post updated Successfully!')
                    return render(request, 'vehicles_app/update_post.html', 
    {
                        'form': form,
                        'formset': formset,
                        'post_form': post_form,
                        'post_id': post_id,
                    })
                else:
                    print(form.errors, formset.errors)
            else:
                form = AddFile()
                formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=PostPicture.objects.none())
            return render(request, 'vehicles_app/update_post.html', {'form': 
    form, 'formset': formset, 'post_form':post_form, 'post_id': post_id})
```

here's my update_post.html

```
                    <form id="post_form" method="post" action="{% url 
                                 'vehicles_app:update_post' post_id %}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="title">Ad Title</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Type Here" 
                           value='{{ form.initial.title }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="city">City</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <select name="city"  value='{{ form.initial.city }}'>
                      <option selected="selected" 
                              value="islamabad">Islamabad</option>
                      <option value="karachi">Karachi</option>
                      <option value="lahore">Lahore</option>
                      <option value="peshawar">Peshawar</option>
                      <option value="quetta">Quetta</option>
                      <option value="multan">Multan</option>
                      <option value="faisalabad">Faisalabad</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="price">Price</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Type Here" 
                      value='{{ form.initial.price }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="brand" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <select name="brand" value='{{ form.initial.brand }}'>
                      <option selected="selected" 
                          value="honda">Honda</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                      <option value="suzuki">Suzuki</option>
                      <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
                      <option value="lexus">Lexus</option>
                      <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
                      <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
                      <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
                      <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                      <option value="daewoo">Daewoo</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="modelyear">Model-Year</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modelyear" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="modelyear" 
                     placeholder="ie:1970-2018"  value='{{ 
                                  form.initial.modelyear }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                  </div>
                <div class="condition" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                  <select name="condition"  value='{{ form.initial.condition 
                                                          }}'>
                    <option selected="selected" value="new">NEW</option>
                    <option value="used">USED</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="mileage">Mileage</label>
                  </div>
                <div class=mileage style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="mileage" placeholder="ie:50000"  
                               value='{{ form.initial.mileage }}' required>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                <br>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="details">Type details here</label>
                  </div>
                <div class="details" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                  <textarea name="details" rows="9" cols="45" value='{{ 
                       form.initial.details }}' required></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>


                {{ formset.management_form }}
                  {% if formset %}
                    {% for form in formset %}
                      {% if form %}
                      <table class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{ form }}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}


                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" 
                       class="btn btn-info" id="post_btn">
                  <input type=button class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" 
                       onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
            </form>
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. You might get more responses if you can create a simple example that shows the problem. At the moment your question includes a huge amount of code, which would take a long time to read through and understand.

Comment: @Alasdair i have deleted some code but i'm stuck in this problem please help me here or my other original post because i'm waiting for solution and no one replied me for the solution,kindly help me

Comment: I would edit the other question, because this one is closed. Sorry, there is still too much code there for me to help you.

Comment: @Alasdair sorry,i'm going to update my other question, i hope you'll help me solving this issue